# Google Analytics Ecommerce tracking doesn´t track

Tags: google-analytics

I have an AngularJS1.0.7 web application. I integrated Google Analytics and now I´m trying to enable ecommerce tracking. However for some reason is not working.

I don´t want to paste all my code, but just let me know if you need it. I installed GA debug extension in Chrome, so these are my traces. It looks like it´s working, I don´t see any error log, however I don´t see any updates in Conversion section of my Real Time section of Google Analytics. Page tracking and event tracking are working.

GA debug Log:

```
analytics_debug.js:9 Executing Google Analytics commands.
analytics_debug.js:9 Running command: ga("ecommerce:addTransaction", {id: 7154})
angular.js:5754 Item tracked 7154 1 Velero - Bavaria Cruiser - 37 Velero - Mallorcá (Islas Baleares) 2 1
analytics_debug.js:9 Executing Google Analytics commands.
analytics_debug.js:9 Running command: ga("ecommerce:addItem", {id: 7154, name: "Velero - Bavaria Cruiser - 37"})
angular.js:5754 Transaction pushed Success!
analytics_debug.js:9 Executing Google Analytics commands.
analytics_debug.js:9 Running command: ga("ecommerce:send")
analytics_debug.js:9 
Sent beacon:
v=1&_v=j37d&a=2127294561&t=transaction&_s=10&dl=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fes&dp=%2Fes%2Freserva-barco&ul=es&de=UTF-8&dt=Yanpy%20-%20Alquiler%20de%20velero%20Bavaria%20Cruiser%20-%2037%20en%20Palma%20de%20Mallorca%2C%20Mallorca%20(Islas%20Baleares)&sd=24-bit&sr=1280x800&vp=1265x354&je=1&fl=17.0%20r0&_u=SCCAAEIRI~&jid=&cid=453263414.1433178376&tid=UA-59702007-2&ti=7154&z=114839439


analytics_debug.js:9 _j1              (&jid) 
analytics_debug.js:9 adSenseId        (&a)   2127294561
analytics_debug.js:9 apiVersion       (&v)   1
analytics_debug.js:9 clientId         (&cid) 453263414.1433178376
analytics_debug.js:9 ec:id            (&ti)  7154
analytics_debug.js:9 encoding         (&de)  UTF-8
analytics_debug.js:9 flashVersion     (&fl)  17.0 r0
analytics_debug.js:9 hitType          (&t)   transaction
analytics_debug.js:9 javaEnabled      (&je)  1
analytics_debug.js:9 language         (&ul)  es
analytics_debug.js:9 location         (&dl)  http://localhost/es
analytics_debug.js:9 page             (&dp)  /es/reserva-barco
analytics_debug.js:9 screenColors     (&sd)  24-bit
analytics_debug.js:9 screenResolution (&sr)  1280x800
analytics_debug.js:9 title            (&dt)  Yanpy - Alquiler de velero Bavaria Cruiser - 37 en Palma de Mallorca, Mallorca (Islas Baleares)
analytics_debug.js:9 trackingId       (&tid) UA-59702007-2
analytics_debug.js:9 viewportSize     (&vp)  1265x354
analytics_debug.js:9 
Sent beacon:
v=1&_v=j37d&a=2127294561&t=item&_s=11&dl=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fes&dp=%2Fes%2Freserva-barco&ul=es&de=UTF-8&dt=Yanpy%20-%20Alquiler%20de%20velero%20Bavaria%20Cruiser%20-%2037%20en%20Palma%20de%20Mallorca%2C%20Mallorca%20(Islas%20Baleares)&sd=24-bit&sr=1280x800&vp=1265x354&je=1&fl=17.0%20r0&_u=SCCAAEIRI~&jid=&cid=453263414.1433178376&tid=UA-59702007-2&ti=7154&in=Velero%20-%20Bavaria%20Cruiser%20-%2037&z=421414866


analytics_debug.js:9 _j1              (&jid) 
analytics_debug.js:9 adSenseId        (&a)   2127294561
analytics_debug.js:9 apiVersion       (&v)   1
analytics_debug.js:9 clientId         (&cid) 453263414.1433178376
analytics_debug.js:9 ec:id            (&ti)  7154
analytics_debug.js:9 ec:item name     (&in)  Velero - Bavaria Cruiser - 37
analytics_debug.js:9 encoding         (&de)  UTF-8
analytics_debug.js:9 flashVersion     (&fl)  17.0 r0
analytics_debug.js:9 hitType          (&t)   item
analytics_debug.js:9 javaEnabled      (&je)  1
analytics_debug.js:9 language         (&ul)  es
analytics_debug.js:9 location         (&dl)  http://localhost/es
analytics_debug.js:9 page             (&dp)  /es/reserva-barco
analytics_debug.js:9 screenColors     (&sd)  24-bit
analytics_debug.js:9 screenResolution (&sr)  1280x800
analytics_debug.js:9 title            (&dt)  Yanpy - Alquiler de velero Bavaria Cruiser - 37 en Palma de Mallorca, Mallorca (Islas Baleares)
analytics_debug.js:9 trackingId       (&tid) UA-59702007-2
analytics_debug.js:9 viewportSize     (&vp)  1265x354
```

**UPDATE:** 
I have just noticed there is an Objetive or Goal column (I don´t know how it´s displayed in english version, I see it in spanish) in the Conversion section of Real-Time. Do I need to configure an Objetive before getting ecommerce conversion tracking info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ecommerce transactions cannot be tracked in Real-Time reports. You could probably set up an event to track successful transactions if you want to see them in real-time, not a goal conversion because goals are only tracked once per session.

If your transactions go to a "Thank you" page, then you could even possibly just check the contents report and see if you see that particular page.

Comment: All right. Today, I can see yesterday´s transactions conversion info in Ecommerce. However, Why there is a Conversions menu in real-time. What and When do you see info there?

Comment: Those are for goal conversions. You can test it out for yourself by creating a test goal. Once you save it, then if you go to Real-Time reports, under conversions you will see that goal.